# How do you change the order of Django's SelectDateWidget to day, month, year?

Tags: django, django-forms

This is the form:

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Entry

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        this_year = datetime.date.today().year
        years = range(this_year-100, this_year+1)
        years.reverse()
        self.fields["date_of_birth"].widget = SelectDateWidget(years=years)
```

The date of birth field is rendered like so

[image]

How do I change it so that it will render as day, month, year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the source code of this widget I see the the order of dropdowns is defined by `DATE_FORMAT` setting:

```
    format = get_format('DATE_FORMAT')
    escaped = False
    output = []
    for char in format:
        if escaped:
            escaped = False
        elif char == '\\':
            escaped = True
        elif char in 'Yy':
            output.append(year_html)
        elif char in 'bFMmNn':
            output.append(month_html)
        elif char in 'dj':
            output.append(day_html)
```

Try to change `DATE_FORMAT` in settings.py to `j N, Y` for example.

Comment: I am 40 seconds faster! Yay! :-)

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to set USE_L10N to False to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `django/forms/extras/widgets.py` where SelectDateWidget is defined the render function contains this snippet of code.

```
 90         output = []
 91         for field in _parse_date_fmt():
 92             if field == 'year':
 93                 output.append(year_html)
 94             elif field == 'month':
 95                 output.append(month_html)
 96             elif field == 'day':
 97                 output.append(day_html)
 98         return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

`_parse_date_fmt` uses `get_format('DATE_FORMAT')`

It looks like `DATE_FORMAT` can be set in the settings.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format