# Django DATE_FORMAT in settings.py ignoring formatting or being overwritten

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-settings

I am trying to change the format of `SelectDateWidget` I have followed the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136830/how-do-you-change-the-order-of-djangos-selectdatewidget-to-day-month-year) including setting `USE_L10N` to `False` I have also looked at the [list of acceptable format strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) and tried multiple combinations.

The issue is that no matter how I format the string the "Year" drop down is always on the left when I want it on the right. It also always formats to 4 digits even if I specify 2. I am however able to remove it altogether by simply not specifying it.

Can anyone tell me how to format the date in "Day : Moth Year"?

I am using Django 1.6.2

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Dublin'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = True
```

These are some of the formats I have tried and the outcome. Month(long) =  "January" etc.

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'j N, Y'    # Year(4 digit) : Month(long) : Day
DATE_FORMAT = 'j N, y'    # Year(4 digit) : Month(long) : Day
DATE_FORMAT = 'j N'       # Month(long) : Day
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'    # Year(4 digit) : Day : Month(long)
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, y'    # Year(4 digit) : Day : Month(long)
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j'       # Day : Month(long)
DATE_FORMAT = 'N, j, Y'   # Year(4 digit) : Day : Month(long)
DATE_FORMAT = 'd, F, Y'   # Year(4 digit) : Month(long) : Day
DATE_FORMAT = 'd, F, y'   # Year(4 digit) : Month(long) : Day
```

I am trying to render `birthdate` below which is part of my Person Model created using ModelForm

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):

    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) #overwritten in forms.py
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.extras import SelectDateWidget

class SurveyFormA(forms.ModelForm):

    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(), required=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectDateWidget` will use `DATE_FORMAT`, but only for the order of year, months and days, nothing more. You can see in the widget code itself that it doesn't distinguish between `y` and `Y` or `b` and `F`, etc.:

```
        elif char in 'Yy':
            output.append('year')
            #if not self.first_select: self.first_select = 'year'
        elif char in 'bEFMmNn':
            output.append('month')
            #if not self.first_select: self.first_select = 'month'
        elif char in 'dj':
            output.append('day')
            #if not self.first_select: self.first_select = 'day'
```

But what's strange in your case is that the parsing seems to be working, but is displayed in reverse. `j N, Y`  should give you the opposite of what you get. So, one thing you should try is put your `DATE_FORMAT` in reverse. Like this for example:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'YNj'
```

That being said, you should maybe have a look at your HTML, probably something in the styling that causes this. A `float: right` somewhere maybe?

As for the 2 digits year, you can pass an argument for the years you want displayed. This can be a list/tuple. See:

> Takes one optional argument:
>
> years
>
> An optional list/tuple of years to use in the “year” select
>   box. The default is a list containing the current year and the next 9
>   years.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/

Like this:

```
birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=('15','16','17','18','19')), required=False)
```

Comment: You are correct. The `float: right` that was causing the three select options to flip over horizontally. Using  `DATE_FORMAT = 'YNj'` allows me to keep all the select fields aligned to the right while still having them in the right order. Thanks